# Importing a Model at diff places by exporting it once using MEF

Tags: c#, mef

In my solution I have a scenario where I need to use the shared instances of the model class, which is being set in one class and the getting the value in other class, the whole process is done through MEF. The scenario is as below:

I exported a `Model` class like this:

```
[Export(typeof(Model1))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
Class Model1
{
   int x;
}
```

... from one project. Later, I imported the constructor of other class:

```
Class XXX
{
    private Model1 ob1;
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public XXX([Import] Model1 ob)
    {
        ob1 = ob
        ob1.x=1; //Setting some values here
    }
}

Class YYY
{
    private Model1 ob1;
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public YYY([Import] Model1 ob)
    {
        ob1 = ob;
        ob1.x=1; //Setting some values here
    }
}
```

Can you please give suggestions for what needs to be done to get the same instance of `Model1` model?

Answer (score 0):

In your BootStrapper code  override the method ConfigureContainer and add the dependencies that you want and instantiate them

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
        base.ConfigureContainer();    
        this.Container.ComposeExportedValue<Model1>(new Model1());
}
```

As you are exporting model as **Shared**(singleton),make sure that you are not instantiating the model anywhere in the code , else the dependency injection will broken, and you will end up getting a new instance of the Model1 class which is no the case you are expecting.